# Disabling intel_pstate in CentOS 7.7

Tags: centos

Im trying to disable pstate for Xeon Gold 5120 running kernel 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64. Everything so far has failed.

I've updated grub with cmd default:

```
intel_pstate=disable
```

I've blacklisted the driver in /etc/modprobe.d

I've tried manually setting cpu min / max frequencies in /sys/devices/system/cpu

I've tried using their cli while the module is enabled:

```
cpupower --cpu all frequency-set --freq {n}MHz
```

Yet invariably our clock speed on all cores is being throttled.

Anyone have experience with this in Cent. Arch forums are suggesting this might be compiled into the kernel?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I think it was either a grub/grub2 or UEFI issue. Initially I had:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Didn't work, then tried both:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

And boom, no more idiotic throttling.